# Formatting a sharepoint workflow email table using HTML Tags

Tags: html, email, sharepoint, workflow, lookup

I'm setting up a workflow email that takes values from a sharepoint form and then formats that email for users.

I've gotten everything working correctly, except for one part. When the email is sent out, the field that is being looked up doesn't get word-wrapped which then causes my emails(including the table) to expand straight across the screen.

Here's a snippet of the code. (Sharepoint 2013 Designer needs to have everything as one long string, which makes it a pain to edit. Probably run it through an online HTML editor to see what is going on)

```
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 316pt; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; COLGROUP: " width=165 124pt? WIDTH:>
<COLGROUP>
    <COL style="WIDTH: 192pt" width=256>
<TBODY>
    <TR style="HEIGHT: 14.25pt" height=19>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; HEIGHT: 14.25pt; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 124pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" height=19 width=165> <FONT size=2>Service ID</FONT> </TD>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 192pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" width=256><FONT size=2>[%Current Item:Service ID%]</FONT></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR style="HEIGHT: 14.25pt" height=19>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; HEIGHT: 14.25pt; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 124pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" height=19 width=165><FONT size=2>Order ID</FONT></TD>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 192pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" width=256><FONT size=2>[%Current Item:Order ID%]</FONT></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR style="HEIGHT: 14.25pt" height=19>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; HEIGHT: 14.25pt; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 124pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" height=19 width=165><FONT size=2>Account ID</FONT></TD>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 192pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" width=256><FONT size=2>[%Current Item:Account ID%]</FONT></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR style="HEIGHT: 14.25pt" height=19>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; HEIGHT: 14.25pt; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 124pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" height=19 width=165><FONT size=2>Change Type</FONT></TD>
        <TD class=xl63 style="WORD-WRAP: break-word; BORDER-TOP: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-RIGHT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; WIDTH: 192pt; BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BORDER-LEFT: windowtext 0.5pt solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" width=256><FONT size=2>[%Current Item:Change Type%]</FONT></TD>
    </TR></Table>
```

I used style="WORD-WRAP: break-word;" which works in sharepoint designer for pre-filled data but it doesn't work for the lookup values. I've looked around but i'm stumped.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can post the resultant HTML output with some of the values filled in? I'm not interested in the actual data, but in whether SharePoint is adding some extra HTML when it replaces those `[%Current Item:Field%]` tokens.

Comment: You refer to a class called xl63. You didn't post the class, so it's hard to tell what is happening. Your `<table>` tag is a mess. You specify a width of 316pt, then later declare `width=165`, the declare `WIDTH:`. I suggest you clean this up, remove. any .25 point sizes and round things up or down.

Comment: I'm not sure how to show the resultant HTML output because this gets processed through sharepoint and sent as an email. The email headers are then encrypted.